# Start a Fragment From An Activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I Recently used this to start A `Fragment` From `Activity` in Navigation Bar Activity (In The                                                                                          `OnListItemClick()` ) :

```
            case 3:
            fragment = new CommunityFragment();

            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new PagesFragment();
            getActionBar().hide();
            break;
        case 5:
            fragment = new WhatsHotFragment();
            break;
        case 6:
            fragment = new MyFragment();
            break;
        case 7:
            fragment = new Views();
            break;
        case 8:
            fragment = new editText();
            break;
```

The problem is that  The fragment is not opening on top of Main Activity on Click of Button after

Instantiating the fragment with its default constructor .

But Now I'm trying to the same but its not working :

```
MainActivity.java
```

XML of MainActivity has A button As :

```
        <com.gc.materialdesign.views.ButtonFlat
        android:id="@+id/buttonflat"
        android:onClick="startFrag"
        android:layout_width="230dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:text="Button" />
```

and in Java Of MainActivity:(On Click Of Button )

```
   public void startFrag(View v) 
    {

       fragment = new Frag_FAB();
   }
```

java of fragment:

```
 public class Frag_FAB extends Fragment {

      public Frag_FAB() {
      }


      @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_find_people,container,false);
        return view;
       }


      }
```

Xml oF Fragment :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:background="#010008"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtLabel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/stuff"
    android:textColor="@color/highlighted_text_material_dark"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:textSize="16dp" />


 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the fragment transaction after the switch statement:

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.add(R.id.container, fragment);
```

your code must be something like:

```
switch(position){
...
...
...
        case 3:
            fragment = new CommunityFragment();

            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new PagesFragment();
            getActionBar().hide();
            break;
        case 5:
            fragment = new WhatsHotFragment();
            break;
        case 6:
            fragment = new MyFragment();
            break;
        case 7:
            fragment = new Views();
            break;
        case 8:
            fragment = new editText();
            break;
...
        }
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.container, fragment); //* Here you add the fragment! :)
```

Comment: Thanks. I did not saw that .

Answer (score 0):

You have to add your fragment to the FragmentManager. Here is an example :

`FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
 fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add it to the layout via a `FragmentTransaction`:

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.add(R.id.container, fragment);
```